# SharePoint designer 2013 not opening site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, developer

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premises site. I want to open site in SharePoint designer but it is not opening in SharePoint designer 2013. It is showing below error:

> Server error: The Version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation running on the server is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer you are using. You need a more recent version of SharePoint Designer.

Comment: try the following 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-designer-error-the-version-of-microsoft/92ec4ad6-3ffc-40b8-8814-0ef8db4ce7de

Answer (score 1):

Try as following:

1. Open SharePoint Designer 2013 then click Account.
2. Sign out and sign in again with the right account to access the SharePoint site.
3. Restart SharePoint Designer 2013.
4. Open the SharePoint site again.

If the issue still exist, clear SharePoint designer cache via deleting everything from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`and `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`.

Restart the computer to compare the result.